# How can I prevent "hyperref" messing up the graphics layout?

Tags: hyperref

```
%
\documentclass{book} %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %
\usepackage{titletoc} %
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} % define colors, color table, order important
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=normalsize,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space,position=below]{caption} % 08_03_2014
\usepackage[position=below,textfont=normal,labelfont=bf]{caption,subfig} % 08_03_2014 (subfig from package)
\usepackage[dvips=true,pdftex=true,verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop} % a4=210mm x 297mm
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} % 1mm=2.834646pt; 1pt=0.3515mm
%
\frontmatter

\definecolor{DarkCream}{rgb}{1.00,1.00,0.85} % FFFFFB
\definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.00,0.00} % #880000

\begin{document}

\vspace{6pt}
\noindent The border at the top of the graphic changes according to whether dvi or pdf is chosen.

\noindent It is the pdf that I want to finish - with a uniform border.

\vspace{6pt}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners,draw=DarkRed,line width=0.7pt,inner sep=2pt,inner ysep=4.8pt] 
    \node at (0,0) [rectangle,draw,fill=DarkCream]{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{119.4mm}
        \subfloat[{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont{\hspace{0.6pt}Inequality region}}]
        {\label{fig:inequalityregion}
        \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{../my_book/chap_02_function_figs/fig_06a_inequality_2x-3y_leq_4}} %
        \hspace{0.4pt}\subfloat[\hspace{1.2pt}Proof of inequality] %
            {\label{fig:inequalityproof}
            \hspace{1.0pt}\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{../my_book/chap_02_function_figs/fig_06b_proof_inequality_2x-3y_leq_4}}
    \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\hspace{3.2pt}Region satisfying the inequality}
  \label{fig:twodiminequalityregion}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your code can not be compiled and hyperref have nothing with this. In figure is completely wrong. you can not put `subloat` into node!  Later I will try to clean-up your code.

Comment: Sorry Zarko, it appears to compile (with no errors) on MikTex 2.9 - I've just double-checked.

Comment: Removing the \hyperref cures the problem - but, of course, I need hyperref.

Comment: I get the same output with pdflatex and latex. Not sure what's the question.

Comment: @Zarko Works fine here. And why do you say that a `\subfloat` can't be placed within a `node`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I'm not sure anymore. My test show me errors, but meanwhoile I have experienced troubles with Windows 10 (unfortunately I was forced to install them) and WinEdt settings, which I didn't succeed to manage yet (missing package don't install on the fly anymore, consequently I receive strange errors). Hopefully I will fix this remedy soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I can not compile your code. So I rearrange it on the way, as I usually manage similar situation.

- any package in which is used in document I load only one
- package with option (as `caption`, `subfig`,...) I load separately

Your construction of figure is very unusual and I doubt that the can be compiled (well, some comment report differently). So I rearrange your code as follows:

```
\documentclass{book} %
\usepackage[verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop} 

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %
\usepackage{titletoc} %
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % define colors, color table, order important
    \definecolor{DarkCream}{rgb}{1.00,1.00,0.85} % FFFFFB
    \definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.00,0.00} % #880000
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage[margin=10pt,
            font=normalsize,
            labelfont=bf,
            labelsep=space,
            position=below]{caption} % 08_03_2014
\usepackage[position=below,
            textfont=normal,
            labelfont=bf]{subfig} % 08_03_2014 (subfig from package)
%\usepackage{float}         % is it really necessary?
%\usepackage{subfloat}      % it is not used
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} % 1mm=2.834646pt; 1pt=0.3515mm
%
%\frontmatter 5<--- here it hasnt any function
    \tikzset{fig/.style = {
mynode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                 draw=DarkRed, line width=0.7pt, fill=DarkCream,
                 inner sep=2pt, inner ysep=4.8pt, align=center}}}


    \begin{document}
The border at the top of the graphic changes according to whether dvi or pdf is chosen.

It is the pdf that I want to finish - with a uniform border.


\begin{figure}[htp]
\subfloat[Inequality region \label{fig:inequalityregion}]
    {\tikz[fig]\node[mynode,text width=0.48\hsize] {\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}};
    }
\hfill 
\subfloat[Proof of inequality \label{fig:inequalityproof}]
    {\tikz[fig]\node[mynode,text width=0.48\hsize]    {\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-b}};
    }
    \caption{\hspace{3.2pt}Region satisfying the inequality}
  \label{fig:twodiminequalityregion}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Which gives with `pdflatex` the following image:

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

**Edit:**
Well, above solution seems not to be, what you looking for. Is then this one?

[image]

For it I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{book} %
\usepackage[verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %
\usepackage{titletoc} %
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % define colors, color table, order important
    \definecolor{DarkCream}{rgb}{1.00,1.00,0.85} % FFFFFB
    \definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.00,0.00} % #880000
%\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - for this example not really essential
\usepackage[margin=10pt,
            font=normalsize,
            labelfont=bf,
            labelsep=space,
            position=below]{caption} % 08_03_2014
\usepackage[position=below,
            textfont=normal,
            labelfont=bf]{subfig} % 08_03_2014 (subfig from package)
%\usepackage{float}         % is it really necessary?
%\usepackage{subfloat}      % it is not used
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} % 1mm=2.834646pt; 1pt=0.3515mm
%
%\frontmatter 5<--- here it hasn't any function

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens}

    \begin{document}
The border at the top of the graphic changes according to whether dvi or pdf is chosen.

It is the pdf that I want to finish - with a uniform border.


\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=DarkRed,colback=DarkCream]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hspace{2em}}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\hsize]{example-image-a}
&
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\hsize]{example-image-b} \\
\parbox{0.45\hsize}{\captionof{subfigure}{Inequality region \label{fig:inequalityregion}}}
&
\parbox{0.45\hsize}{\captionof{subfigure}{Proof of inequality \label{fig:inequalityproof}}}
\end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \caption{Region satisfying the inequality}
\label{fig:twodiminequalityregion}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

As you can see, I put `subfigures` in `tcolorbox` where I only define color of frame and background and left selection of other parameters to you. For sub captions I use `captionof` facility of caption package, which enable to use it outside of float environment.

**Edit (2):**
Distance between images and between images I select such that they are approximately balanced. This distances are controlled by:

- between images width @{\hspace{}}, where `<width>` you can select according to your taste. If the distance provided by `\tabcolsep` is adequate, than it should be omitted.
- distance between images and sub captions is controlled by `\arraystrech`. Here I use default settings
- distance between table and border of `tcolorbox` is determined by its settings. I use default value, but you can define other values, for example

  `top=1mm, bottom=1mm, left=1mm, right=1mm,`

if you like to have only 1 mm distance between border and images. You can also define width of `tcolorox`. Used default setting is `textwidth`. For details please red `tcolorbox` manual.

Comment: It looks good but I cannot check properly tonight (UK).

Comment: The problem was that the border at the top - while being correct in the dvi compilation, then increased by at least 20pt under the pdf compilation.  Everything else remained consistent under both compilations.  I think your answer solves the problem.  Thanks for the  moment.

Comment: Zarko,  I see you have placed two separate background borders - one around each picture.  Would it be difficult to use one border around the pair, please?

Comment: I have tried to adapt your syntax to get a single background for the pair of pics but, so far, to no avail.  However, I am convinced your method will work.

Comment: @keith77777, you mean that sub-caption is also included in single colored frame? This is with given example is not possible. For it you (me?) need to look for different approach.

Comment: @keith77777, see upgrade of my answer.

Comment: Zarko Yes, your modified answer is what I want, and I am most impressed by your expertise.  Only one thing remains: the control over the dimensions that dictate the background size.  For example, where is it picking up its value for \hspace?  How can I control the background size and the gap between the pics?

Comment: @keith, see recent editing of my question. I believe that now I answer on all your sub-requests :-), so it is time for vote/accept of my answer :-) :-). For further help (since we are almost on the limit of allowed comments) I suggest you to ask new question.

Comment: I would like thank Zarko for his/her patience and the exceptional attention to detail.